GPO doesn't Install locally located MSI on boot on all PCs
I'm using GPO cache to install software during boot on offline computers.
It's only working on 50% of the test computers.
It's a 2 step process:

GPO1 copies the MSI to a local folder on all computers when they are conneted to a VPN (this works 100%)
GPO2 installs the software that was copied by GPO1 while booting, even if offline

GPO2 is a common "Policies\Software Settings\Assigned Applications" GPO that points to an MSI located on "C:\folder"
On the computers where the software doesn't install, we can find the events below, related to unavailability of network access.
But the MSI file is on the local disk of every machine.
Does it make sense?
How can I get this to work?

The assignment of application [app-name] from policy [policy-name] failed. The error was : %%1274
The removal of the assignment of application [app-name]  from policy [policy-name] failed. The error was : %%2
Failed to apply changes to software installation settings. The installation of software deployed through Group Policy for this user has been delayed until the next logon because the changes must be applied before the user logon. The error was : %%1274
The Group Policy Client Side Extension Software Installation was unable to apply one or more settings because the changes must be processed before system startup or user logon. The system will wait for Group Policy processing to finish completely before the next startup or logon for this user, and this may result in slow startup and boot performance.


I know it's offline, but does the setting "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" is set ? I ask as I see your two last error, which prompt to me that the GPO didnt had time to run before the user login. Even if offline, that will make the net stack open and applies correctly the GPO before the user is prompted to log.

Group Policy environment debug logging will show you it is the network connection and it needs to be configured to wait.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Group+Policy+environment+debug+logging+site%3Aserverfault.com&client=ms-android-google&sca_esv=8555417468704b0c&sca_upv=1&sxsrf=ADLYWIIr1ZyOLf1AFEtyyN6he-qcGvPMVA%3A1722001654233&ei=9qijZsvwDa-15NoPxaitgAo&oq=Group+Policy+environment+debug+logging+site%3Aserverfault.com

Yes, there is another policy that sets "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" to "enabled" and "Specify maximum wait time for Group Policy scripts" is also set. I tried even at 7200 seconds, to no avail. The same computers still get the errors. All the computers, the ones that install and the ones that error out,  belong to the same OU and ADGroup.
